# Split String from Variable

Tags: add-on, plugin

I've got a variable that outputs a string such as:

```
question ^ answer > question ^ answer > question ^ answer
```

Now, I added the symbols in between them to know where the split should happen. I've been using the 'Explode' plugin (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/explode) and this works perfectly. BUT it only works to split based on one set of characters e.g. ^ only.

```
{variable} = question 1 ^ answer 1 > question 2 ^ answer 2

{exp:explode separator=">" string="{variable}"}

    <div id="question">
        {exp_value}
    </div>

 {/exp:explode}
```

The above code would output:

```
    <div id="question">
        question 1 ^ answer 1
    </div>

    <div id="question">
        question 2 ^ answer 3
    </div>
```

Which is great, but I need my markup to be like this:

```
    <div id="question">
        question 1
    </div>

    <div id="answer">
        answer 1
    </div>
```

Which would require doing something like:

```
{variable} = question 1 ^ answer 1 > question 2 ^ answer 2

{exp:explode separator="^|>" string="{variable}"}

    <div id="question">
        {exp_value_1}
    </div>

    <div id="answer">
        {exp_value_2}
    </div>

 {/exp:explode}
```

Which would then output:

```
    <div id="question">
        question 1
    </div>

    <div id="answer">
        answer 1
    </div>

    <div id="question">
        question 2
    </div>

    <div id="answer">
        answer2
    </div>
```

Now the Explode plugin comes with the `{exp_value_1}` and `{exp_value_2}` variables, but they don't work on a 'Loop'

Is there any way of achieving this? With any other plugin? Or another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this with the Lists feature of CE Variables.

http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-variables/user-guide/lists

Comment: I'll give this a go. It certainly looks like it might work.